# Vector space notation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Explain which of the following vector spaces are subspaces of eachother

${\cal C}(\mathbb{R})$

${\cal C}^n(\mathbb{R})$ (for different $n$)

${\cal C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.

I do not understand what ${\cal C}$, $n$ and $\mathbb{R}$ means in this context? Could someone clarify?

Comment: Usually C^n means n-th derivative is continuous.

Comment: The first set is the set of *continuous* functions defined on $\mathbf R$, the second is the set of $n$-*times continuously differentiable functions* on $\mathbf R$ and the last one, the set of *infinitely differentiable functions* on $\mathbf R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathcal{C}^n(\mathbb{R})$ usually denotes the set of $n$-times continuously differentiable functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ or to $\mathbb{C}$ but that does not really matter.

Comment: Does this mean ${\cal C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is a subspace of ${\cal C}^n(\mathbb{R})$ which is a subspace of ${\cal C}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: yes, as one prescribes less regularity.

Answer (score 0):

$C^n(\mathbb R)$ undoubtedly stands for *n times continuously differentiable functions* defined on the field of real numbers...

$C^{\infty}(\mathbb R)\subset C^m(\mathbb R)\subset C^n(\mathbb R)\subset C(\mathbb R)$ for $m\gt n$ and each $C^n(\mathbb R)$ is easily seen to be a vector space over $\mathbb R$.